# jquery: can't get .click method to work

Tags: jquery

I'm simply trying to add some content on click but somehow my code isn't working, I don't think html is needed for this one.

```
$("div").click(function(){
    $("p").after("<p>das</p>");
});
```

Comment: where is your script located... is it in a dom ready handler... whether the `div` is present in the dom when your script is executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").click(function(){
      $("p").after("<p>das</p>");
    });
});
```

Or before doing `after()` you should `alert()` or `console.log()` a message to verify your click handler works.

Comment: Thanks, everything worked fine, I'll accept your answer in 10mins.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").click(function(){
    $("p").after("<p>das</p>");
});
});
```

Wrap your code inside DOM ready function.

**Demo:**
    http://jsfiddle.net/x3QQx/

Answer (score 0):

Did you load proper jQuery framework?

HTML:

```
<div><p>paragraph</p></div>
```

JS:

```
$("div").click(function(){
    $("p").after("<p>das</p>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9RE4W/